# How to remove gift options tab from Product edit page in Magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, product, admin

I have to need to remove gift option tab in Product edit page Admin side.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Stores --> Attributes(Title) -->  Attribute Sets and remove the Gift Option folder from the set you are using on the product page.

Comment: how about Marketplace vendor and admin wise setting? admin- display, vendor - not display??

Comment: Have you checked your default store view? You could try single store mode?

Comment: yes single store.

Comment: Did you drag the file in attribute sets? See here http://nimb.ws/BfMRHV

Comment: @Will Lifestyle drag not working